# Can't import MinMaxScaler "from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler"

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I run into the following error when running my script. Could someone please let me know what the issue could be? I have installed Sklearn on my system, and using "pip list" I can see 'sklearn 0.0" is present.

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas_datareader\compat\__init__.py:7: FutureWarning:

pandas.util.testing is deprecated. Use the functions in the public API at pandas.testing instead.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 9, in <module>
    import sklearn.preprocessing
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
ImportError: cannot import name '__check_build' from partially initialized module 'sklearn' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py)
```

Code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import math
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
```

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to only the relevant part. See [mcve]

Comment: It should be obvious that 1) when you face an error in line #9 for one of your imports, you **do not** post [a wall of irrelevant code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/) here that comes after the error, and is therefore never executed (edited out) 2) such questions should be tagged as `scikit-learn`, and irrelevant tags like `plotly-dash` have no place (edited).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out what's causing this issue. some packages are not being installed due to file path length limit on windows. 
In order to fix this I had to:
Type “regedit” in the Windows start menu to launch regedit.

Go to the Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem key.

Edit the value of the LongPathsEnabled property of that key and set it to 1.

Reinstall scikit-learn (ignoring the previous broken installation):
pip install --exists-action=i scikit-learn

for more info visit: 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#troubleshooting

Comment: Interesting problem, nice you could find the solution.